# Operate componentWillMount logic on a StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to code a basic authentication screen with React Native.

Once the user is logged in it will be redirected to its home screen.

To do so I used a `StackNavigator`, as follows:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import LoginPage from './src/pages/login';

const MyApp = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: LoginPage },
  Home: { home: HomePage } 
});

export default MyApp;
```

But I would like to operate some logic here (such as DB init). As this is a pure component I am kind of lost...

How should I proceed? Can I "transform" the `StackNavigator` into a component with lifecycle functions for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `Stacknavigator` object into `React.Component` this way:

```js
const MyAppStack = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: LoginPage },
  Home: { home: HomePage } 
});

class MyApp extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {}
  componentWillUnmount() {}

  render() {
    return <MyAppStack />;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Val , Please help me issue to load ListView : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658124/checked-unchecked-doesnt-working-in-listview-react-native/46658636#46658636

Comment: Why thumb down? please leave a message so I can improve it.

Comment: When you have nested navigators, you loose the parameters wrapping it with another component, which break when you use deep linking or when parameters are passed to the navigator.

Comment: @alexmngn you can still pass in parameters with `{...this.props}`, makes the composition component even more useful.