# React: Loop over data and create rows with three items in a row

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of items, 9 be exact attached to my state:

```
 state =  {
    menuItems: [
        {
            id: 0,
            name: 'Foods',
            iconSrc: 'food.jpg'
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Drinks',
            iconSrc: 'drinks.jpg'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Snacks',
            iconSrc: 'snacks.jpg'
        }
   ]
```

and want to loop over them, however i have 9 items in the array and want to do the following: group every three items in the array under a new div, like so:

```
<div class="row-container">
   <div class="col-4">
        <div class="col-2">Item 1</div>
        <div class="col-2">Item 2</div>
        <div class="col-2">Item 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="col-2">Item 4</div>
        <div class="col-2">Item 5</div>
        <div class="col-2">Item 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="col-2">Item 7</div>
        <div class="col-2">Item 8</div>
        <div class="col-2">Item 9</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I achieve that using the map function within React?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get use of [`modulus`(Reminder)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()). Modulus will tell you the reminder of the division for given integer.

> The remainder operator returns the remainder left over when one
>   operand is divided by a second operand. It always takes the sign of
>   the dividend, not the divisor. It uses a built-in `modulo` function to
>   produce the result, which is the integer remainder of dividing `var1`
>   by `var2`

**Example**

```
this.state.menuItems.map((item, index) => {
  if (((index + 1) % 3) === 1) {

    return (
      <div className="col-4">
      <div className="col-2">{item.name}</div>
    );

  } else if (((index + 1) % 3) === 2) {

    return (<div className="col-2">{item.name}</div>);

  } else if (((index + 1) % 3) === 0) {

    return (
      <div className="col-2">{item.name}</div>
      </div>
    );

  }
});
```

Comment: please help me one issue to reload the listview react native : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658124/checked-unchecked-doesnt-working-in-listview-react-native/46658636#46658636

Comment: You used the word "reminder" (twice) which is a typo of the word "remainder". You are missing an "a" in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your question correctly, this should work, let me know if this is what you meant please

```
renderMenuItems() {
    let items = this.state.menuItems.map((item, index) => {
       return ( 
         <div class="col-4" key={item.id}>
          <div class="col-2">{item.id}</div>
          <div class="col-2">{item.name}</div>
          <div class="col-2">{item.iconSrc}</div>
        </div>
       );

   });
   return items;
}
```

Then inside of your render:

```
<div class="row-container">
  {this.renderMenuItems()}
</div>
```

This would create:

```
<div class="row-container">
   <div class="col-4">
        <div class="col-2">0</div>
        <div class="col-2">Foods</div>
        <div class="col-2">food.jpg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="col-2">1</div>
        <div class="col-2">Drinks</div>
        <div class="col-2">drinks.jpg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="col-2">2</div>
        <div class="col-2">Snacks</div>
        <div class="col-2">snacks.jpg</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for `.map()`, this is what I use everywhere, simple and effective. This is also a good answer with clear instructions to solve the question

Answer (score 1):

You can try to transform the array into subset of arrays containing three elements and then map them to spit what you want.

Look here for an example [Split array into chunks of N length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318680/split-array-into-chunks-of-n-length)

Comment: The link led me to the best possible solution to my problem. Thanks.