# Reload render issue after change props using Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I use the redux in my apps. there is only one state is define. I can change the state and render the screen. but whenever i change state props I can't reload the screen.

**Code:**

**action-types.js**

```
export const SET_NOTIFICATION = "SET_NOTIFICATION";
```

**action.js**

```
import {
    SET_NOTIFICATION,
} from "./action-types";

let initialState = {
    notyIndex: 0,
};

export const setNotyIndex = (notyIndex) => ({type: SET_NOTIFICATION, notyIndex});
```

**reducer.js**

```
import {
    SET_NOTIFICATION,
} from "./action-types";

let initialState = {
    notyIndex: 0,
};

export default reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_NOTIFICATION:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {notyIndex: action.notyIndex});
            break;
        default:
            return initialState;
            break;
    }
};
```

**I connect the redux as below. DashBoard.js**

```
import { setNotyIndex } from "./action";
import {connect} from "react-redux"
```

********* LIFE CYCLE START ************

```
 componentWillMount(){
  console.log('Call update');
  console.log('Index is',this.props.notyIndex);
 }

 shouldComponentUpdate=()=>{
    return true
  }
 componentDidUpdate=(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)=>{
    console.log('Call update');
    console.log('Index is',this.props.notyIndex);
  }

 componentDidMount() {
     console.log('Call update');
     console.log('Index is',this.props.notyIndex);
  }
```

********* LIFE CYCLE END ************

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
      setNotyIndex: (notyIndex) => dispatch(setNotyIndex(notyIndex)),
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    if (state === undefined) {
        return {};
    }
    return {
        notyIndex: state.notyIndex,
    }
};


connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DashBoard);
```

**value is set like.**

```
setNotyIndex(1);
```

**- As above code the no one lifecycle method called after set the value.**

Thanks.

Comment: Please add your component code

Comment: @MotiKorets actually I have added all method of lifecycle in my code, No one method is called.

Comment: He meant the component where you call `setNotyIndex`. Did the `setNotyIndex` action or `SET_NOTIFICATION` reducer get called?

Comment: @MotiKorets you can see the life cycle method which is use in my code.

Comment: @riwu I called setNotyIndex on button event.

Comment: add log to your action and reducer to see if it's being called.

Comment: @riwu not called.

Comment: probably something wrong with your `DashBoard` component then.

Comment: are your exporting `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard)` or `export default class Dashboard`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Yes, I will do also same as above

Comment: The reason i asked for the component code is because i suspect the problem is in the way you dispatch your actions.

Comment: Actually, seems that you're calling action directly, so it won't work. Use `this.props.setNotyIndex` instead of `setNotyIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

First when you use redux's Method you must call with

```
this.props.setNotyIndex(1);
```

and When you use redux's veriable in your component you must have you use

```
this.props.notyIndex
```

You can console in your **mapStateToProps** method to get changes like under

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
console.log("State veriable : ", state)
if (state === undefined) {
    return {};
}
return {
    notyIndex: state.notyIndex,
}
```

};

When you change your redux veriable and if you use that veriable in your code then relative component rerender it selt. But if there some issue then you can call setState menually after redux method calling, like under

```
this.props.setNotyIndex(1);
this.setState({
```

});

I hope it work for you.......